# Can't use SQLite with SqlTypeProvider

Tags: .net, sqlite, f#, fslab

I wrote an almost direct copy of FsLab canonical example, but modified it to use a SQLite provider. You can find it here: https://github.com/sergi/FoxStat. The main (and only) script is https://github.com/sergi/FoxStat/blob/master/FoxStats.fsx.

When I run it, I get the following error:

> /.../FoxStat/FoxStats.fsx(26,5): error FS3033:
>   The type provider 'FSharp.Data.Sql.SqlTypeProvider' reported an error:
>   SQLite.Interop.dll, Path:
>   /.../FoxStat/packages/System.Data.SQLite.Core/lib/net451
>   (You are running on x64.)

It seems it has a problem finding `SQLite.Interop.dll`, but I've already tried copying from `packages/System.Data.SQLite.Core/build/net451/x64/SQLite.Interop.dll` (also tried with the x86 version), and it keeps giving the same message.

I am building this on OSX, by the way.

How can I solve this?